# Django- 404 error when embedding Youtube link via frontend post form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Introduction: Hello, I am new to Python and Django. Started my first blog project that enable users to create their blogs from the frontend.

Problems: When I embed a youtube code in the form text area, it will return a 404 (see=image attached).

On the other hand, there is no problem doing it via Django admin panel.

[image: Error given when youtube link is embedded via front end]

Here are the files.

Views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post, Category
from .forms import PostForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render


class HomeView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'home.html'


def CategoryListView(request):
    category_menu_list = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'category_list.html', {'category_menu_list': category_menu_list})


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'


class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'


class AddCategoryView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'add_category.html'
    fields = '__all__'


class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'update_post.html'
    

class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'delete_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')


def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats.replace('-', ' '))
    return render(request, 'categories.html', {'cats': cats.title().replace('-', ' '), 'category_posts': category_posts})
```

Urls.py

```
from .views import HomeView, PostDetailView, AddPostView, UpdatePostView, DeletePostView, AddCategoryView, CategoryView, \
    CategoryListView
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add_post'),
    path('post/edit/<int:pk>', UpdatePostView.as_view(), name='update_post'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete', DeletePostView.as_view(), name='delete_post'),
    path('add_category/', AddCategoryView.as_view(), name='add_category'),
    path('category/<str:cats>/', CategoryView, name='category'),
    path('category_list', CategoryListView, name='category_list'),
    path('post_detail/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

STATUS = (
    (0, "Draft"),
    (1, "Publish")
)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='uncategorized')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget
from .models import Post, Category

choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name')

choice_list = []

for item in choices:
    choice_list.append(item)


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'category', 'content', 'summary', 'status')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Your title here'}),
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Short description'}),
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(choices=choice_list, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'summary': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'status': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Comment: Which form field are you putting the YouTube embed code in? `content`?

Comment: And this `404` response, is it after you POST to `add_post/`?

Comment: yes, form field is content. the 404 response comes after posting to add_post/ or  post/edit/<int:pk>

Comment: I've just seen what's wrong: Django is trying to display a 403 error but it can't find the template.

Comment: You'll need to configure the built-in view for the 403 error. These docs should help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/#module-django.views

Comment: Somehow, your user must not have permission to modify the posts: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view

Comment: But maybe it's something else. Either way, you'll need to configure the built-in views to see what the real error is.

Comment: i will do that.. thanks for the inputs

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the host I used to deploy this app (Namecheap hosting).It was the modsecurity setting that acts like a firewall. After whitelisting the domain name, I can embed youtube links via front-end again.